# How correctly to disable MC SendComplete workflow?

Tags: marketing-cloud, workflow

I've noticed in one implementation we receive emails for each email send that was completed by their Marketing Cloud team (sent via Service Cloud). 
After googling it turns out the notifications are sent via a workflow called SendComplete, can I simply disable this workflow to stop the email notifications or is there a setting somewhere in MC or MC connect to disable the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from this [answer on the Success community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019am3QAA), it seems like a setting in Marketing Cloud Connect that you would need to change:

> When you install Marketing Cloud Connect they now add in many
>   workflows and additional settings that most people aren't aware of,
>   this being one of them.
>
> If you navigate to: Setup > Create > Workflows & Approvals > Email
>   Alerts
>
> [image]
>
> You will see an Email Alert workflow named Send Email Notification of
>   Completed Send. Click on that link, and on the next page you can
>   disable the only rule associated to it named SendComplete.
>
> Hope that helps.

Comment: I should have probably linked to this in my original thread, I found that exact same partner community post. My question is really confirmation that this is the correct way of turning it off? or is there a setting to do this via MC? I ask because there is a field update that is carried out in the same workflow rule so I don't want to just disable it incase it inadvertently affects something else.

Comment: To my knowledge this is the only relevant setting to turn these off.